# get max min element from array, delete them and sum rest of the array

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to get 5 different grades from judges, and putting them in a array.
Then I try to find the max and the min element from the array.
example {2,3,4,5,6}
max= 6 , min = 2.
After that I have to delete 6 and 2, and then add 3+4+5 which gives me a sum of 12.
How do  delete and then add the sum? Since it looks like I am getting errors while deleting from the array .Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int judge1, judge2,judge3,judge4, judge5,i,max,min;
    int size = 4;


    printf("Judge one grade");
    scanf("%d", &judge1);
    printf("Judge one grade");
    scanf("%d", &judge2);
    printf("Judge one grade");
    scanf("%d", &judge3);
    printf("Judge one grade");
    scanf("%d", &judge4);
    printf("Judge one grade");
    scanf("%d", &judge5);
    int a[] = {judge1, judge2, judge3, judge4, judge5};
    max=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
        if(max<a[i])
            max=a[i];
    }

    min=a[0];
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
        if(min>a[i])
            min=a[i];
    }

    for (i=0;i < size ;i++) {
        if(a[i] == min || a[i] == max){
            a[i] = a[i+1];
        }
    }

    for (i=0;i < size ;i++) {
        int sum = 0;
        sum+= a[i];
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It is nice to know that you are trying to do that.  I am trying to find a good plumber.

Comment: @sabbahillel Sorry I was in a hurry while posting, added the question

Comment: FYI looking at your code, you will have the value after the min and the value after the max added twice to the sum. Also if the min or max is the last entry, you will set the last value to something outside the array.

Comment: @sabbahillel I wrote on the top what I want to achieve, the problem is I am not sure how to achieve it.

Comment: Are all of the values positive or do you have negative numbers?

Comment: @sabbahillel all positives

Comment: Note: An array of grades is not needed, just a running min, max and sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looping through the array again, use the index. Note that in your code, you reset sum inside the loop so it will only show the last value and is not in scope when the loop is finished (so it will disappear). You also print inside the loop instead of after the full sum has been calculated.

```
int imin = 0, imax = 0;
max=a[0];
for(i=1; i<size; i++){
    if(max<a[i]) {
        imax = i;
        max=a[i];
    }
}

min=a[0];
for(i=1; i<size; i++){
    if(min>a[i]) {
        min=a[i];
        imin = i;
    }
}

a[imin] = 0; // Does not contribute to the sum
a[imax] = 0; // Does not contribute to the sum

int sum = 0;
for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
    sum += a[i];
}
printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to know how the for loops worked for max and min, solved the rest! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here's your deleting code. The basic idea is if it's the min or max to replace it with the one after it.

```
for (i=0;i < size ;i++) {
    if(a[i] == min || a[i] == max){
        a[i] = a[i+1];
    }
}
```

Ok, let's try it. `{4, 3, 6, 5}`. 3 is min, 6 is max.

```
i == 0
a[0] == 4
a[1] == 3
No change: {4, 3, 6, 5}

i == 1
a[1] == 3 (the min)
a[2] == 6 (the max)
a[1] = a[2]: {4, 6, 6, 5}  /* whoops, you replaced the min with the max */

i = 2
a[2] == 6 (the max)
a[3] == 5
a[2] = a[3]: {4, 6, 5, 5}

i == 3
a[3] == 5
a[4] == garbage /* whoops, you walked off the array */
No change
```

So there's two problems. When you do the replacement you have to recheck the new value. This will be a problem if the min and max or next to each other, or if there's two max values.

Second is you're walking off the array. `i + 1` is a red flag. If the min or max was the last value, you'd replace it with garbage. A memory checker such as [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) will find these sorts of very, very common problems. I highly recommend you always run a memory checker and fix everything it complains about.

---

Rather than altering the array, which gets tricky, it's much easier to do this in two passes. It's also non-destructive, you don't have to alter or copy the data.

1. Find the min and the max.
2. Take the average by ignoring the min and the max.

You can find the min and max in one loop.

```
int min = a[0];
int max = a[0];
for( i = 1; i < size; i++ ) {
    if( a[i] < min ) {
        min = a[i];
    }
    if( a[i] > max ) {
        max = a[i];
    }
}
```

Then take the average and ignore the min and max.

```
int sum = 0;
int count = 0;

for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    if( a[i] != min && a[i] != max ) {
        sum += a[i];
        count++;
    }
}

int avg = sum / count;
```

---

This reveals another problem. What if there are multiple mins and maxes? What if the scores are `{3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5}`? Do you want to throw them all out and get an average of 0? Probably not. You probably only want to throw out the highest and lowest single scores.

You could make `seen_min` and `seen_max` boolean variables to only skip `min` and `max` once, but this gets complicated. [@MikeNakis solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39754300/14660) is better, store the index of the min and max and use that to do the skipping.

```
int min_idx = 0;
int max_idx = 0;
for( i = 1; i < size; i++ ) {
    if( a[i] < a[min_idx] ) {
        min_idx = i;
    }
    if( a[i] > a[max_idx] ) {
        max_idx = i;
    }
}

int sum = 0;
int count = 0;

for( i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
    /* Skip the min and max score */
    if( i == min_idx || i == max_idx ) {
        continue;
    }

    sum += a[i];

    /* You could replace count with size - 2, but this way
       there's one less assumption */
    count++;
}

double avg = (double)sum / count;
```

Comment: In your `i = 2` iteration, `a[3]` should be 5, not 6.

Comment: @8bittree Thanks, fixed! It's easier if next time you suggest these edits with the edit button at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the fix would be too small for me to edit, but in retrospect, the comment ought to have brought me over the threshold.

Answer (score 2):

Logic you used in two for loops is wrong.
1st for loop -

```
for (i=0;i < size ;i++) {
    if(a[i] == min || a[i] == max){
        a[i] = a[i+1];
    }
}
```

Here you are copying next element to previous. Thus for array [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], you'll be copying 3 to 2 so array will become [3, 3, 4, 5, 6] which will give wrong result on summing up.

2nd for loop -

```
for (i=0;i < size ;i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    sum+= a[i];
    printf("%d\n", sum);
}
```

Here you are initializing sum to 0 in every iteration, thus a[i] always will get added to 0. Thus output will be last element value.
You should initialize sum before start of for loop.

**Answer**  -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int judge1=2, judge2=3,judge3=4,judge4=5, judge5=6,i,max,min;
    int size = 5;


    int a[] = {judge1, judge2, judge3, judge4, judge5};
    max=0;
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
        if(a[max]<a[i])
            max=i;
    }
    for (i=max;i<size;i++) {
        a[i] = a[i+1];
    }
    size--;

    min=0;
    for(i=1;i<size;i++){
        if(a[min]>a[i])
            min=i;
    }
    for (i=min;i < size ;i++) {
        a[i] = a[i+1];
    }
    size--;

    int sum = 0;
    for (i=0;i < size ;i++) {
        sum+= a[i];
        printf("%d\n", sum);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or if you just need the sum here's the easy solution

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int judge1=2, judge2 = 3,judge3 = 4,judge4 = 5, judge5 = 6, i;
    int size = 5, sum = 0, max, min;
    int a[] = {judge1, judge2, judge3, judge4, judge5};
    max = a[0]; 
    min = a[0];
    for (i=0;i < size ;i++) {
        if(max<a[i])
            max=a[i];
        if(min>a[i])
            min=a[i];
        sum+= a[i];
    }
    sum = sum - (max + min);
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to even have an array.  Calculate the min, max and sum as you go:

```
unsigned min = -1u;  // min is set to the greatest unsigned value
unsigned max = 0;    // max is set to the least unsigned value
unsigned sum = 0;

for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
  unsigned judge;
  printf("Judge one grade ");
  if (scanf("%u", &judge) != 1) break; // validate input
  if (judge > max) max = judge;
  if (judge < min) min = judge;
  sum += judge;
}

if (min > max) {
  printf("No valid input\n");
  return -1;
}

// print sum less the min and max, which is OP's goal
unsigned sum_less_min_max = sum - min - max;
printf("sum = %u\n", sum_less_min_max);
```

Comment: @sabbahillel `printf("sum = %u\n", sum - min - max);` prints the sum **without** the min or max.

Comment: OK I missed that. Of course using the sum later is still a problem unless you subtract them at the end (near the print). `sum -= (min+max);`

Comment: @sabbahillel  Not much different than a quibble using `a[imax]` later in code finding it is 0 rather than the maximum value as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39754399/2410359).  The point being `min,max,sum,a[]` are _intermediate_ variables and OP's code implies that printing the result was the goal, not necessarily returning a variable containing the value nor maintaining `min, max, sum, i, a[]`, etc.

Comment: Yes you are right. either way it gets the correct sum. It only depends on what he needs to do in the rest of the code.